# How to complete the argument to find the solution of the following non-linear O. D. E.?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The O. D. E. I am trying to solve is 
$$y''(-y')^m=-y^ny',\quad y(1)=1,\quad y'(1)=-1,\quad (*)$$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers greater than one. If we observe that 
$$y''(-y')^m=-\frac{1}{m+1}[(-y)^{m+1}]',$$ 
and that 
$$y^ny'=\frac{1}{n+1}[y^{n+1}]',$$ 
we can integrate the equation ($*$) and obtain the following equation: $-\frac{1}{m+1}(-y')^{m+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}(y)^{n+1}=C$ where $C$ is a constant. From now on, I don't know what to do.

Could someone give me an idea to complete the solution above or show me another way to find $y$ in the equation ($*$)?

Comment: Methinks you are missing a $'$ in the RHS of your original equation (*)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since
$$
y''(-y')^m=\frac{(-1)^m}{m+1}[(y')^{m+1}]'=-y^ny'=-\frac{1}{n+1}(y^{n+1})' 
$$
we have
$$
\frac{(-1)^m}{m+1}(y')^{m+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}y^{n+1}=C, 
$$
and taking into account the initial conditions $y(1)=1=-y'(1)$, we find that
$$
C=\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{m+1}=\frac{m-n}{(n+1)(m+1)}.
$$
So now we have
$$
(y')^{m+1}=(-1)^m\frac{m+1}{n+1}\left(\frac{m-n}{m+1}-y^{n+1}\right),
$$
i.e.
$$
y'=\begin{cases}
a_{m,n}\left(\frac{m-n}{m+1}-y^{n+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{m+1}} & m\ \text{ even }\\
a_{m,n}\left(y^{n+1}-\frac{m-n}{m+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{m+1}} & m\ \text{ odd }
\end{cases},
$$
where
$$\tag{1}
a_{m,n}=\left(\frac{m+1}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{m+1}}.
$$
Hence
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_1^{y(t)}\left[\frac{m-n}{m+1}-u^{n+1}\right]^{-\frac{1}{m+1}}du&=&a_{m,n}(t-1)\quad m\ \text{ even }\tag{2}\\
\int_1^{y(t)}\left[u^{n+1}-\frac{m-n}{m+1}\right]^{-\frac{1}{m+1}}du&=&\pm a_{m,n}(t-1)\quad m\ \text{ odd }\tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}